# change the width of the sidebar in a wordpress layout

Tags: css, wordpress

Im very new to wordpress and responsive layouts designs. I just got a domain and installed wordpress. then i installed a new theme and editing it according to my needs. my website is http://www.laktro.com/wp/ I need to make its sidebar somewhat wider. i need help from an expert in wordpress for that.
here what i have tried. in the css,

```
#secondary{
  width: 22% ;
 }
```

i changed the value 22 to a higher number(26%), then the sidebar goes down of the content. cant find a place to change the width of the content. please help me in this issue. I can provide any additional details or resources needed.

Comment: question not clear

Comment: I need to make the sidebar more wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `style.css` on line 601:

```
#primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -27% 0 0; /* Change the -27% to something lower (like -30%) */
    padding: 0.7em;
    width: 98.2%;
    border-top: 4px solid #666;
}
```

Comment: this works but it again breaks the layout when the screen be smaller than 930px.

Comment: thanks a lot, this answer helped me, i fixed the issue. I increased the margin right of #primary and #content  to 33% and then increased the #secondary width to 26% . Now the problem is solved. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your stylesheet by going to Appearance > Edit CSS and insert:

```
#header, #footer, #wrapper {
width: 1000px;
}
```

You probably want the width to be wider than 1000px pixels since there's built-in padding in the left and right of the content area.

Find Interesting thing:

```
#wrap {
    background-color: #000;
    border-top: 8px none #69c;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin: 0 auto -20px;
    max-width: 960px; //your content area is fixed close this and see changes
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: incerease max-width:960px its automatically increase width of your sideba

Comment: i want to keep the max with in that value and increase the sidebar width and reduce the content width

Comment: .site-main {
    background: #eaeaea none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

Comment: \wp-content\themes\yourtheme\index.php